# How can I import JSON data to Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import

I want to bring data from [PCPartPicker](https://pcpartpicker.com/) to a Google Sheet so I can easily see and compare the lowest prices of different products at a glance. For example, displaying the lowest price for different [graphics cards](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/#sort=price&c=496) or [processors](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/g94BD3/amd-ryzen-5-5600x-37-ghz-6-core-processor-100-100000065box). Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about coding, so my efforts have been blind shots at the dark.

I've been trying to use the [IMPORTJSONAPI](https://github.com/qeet/IMPORTJSONAPI) script extension to import the data, since the default functions can't import data from JSON API, but I haven't had much success in getting anything out of it.

I've tried using Chrome Dev Tools and copying the selector/JS Path of the element I want into the JSONPath Query of the function, but that always results in this error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Also, the text I get out of copying the element selector/JS Path looks very different from JSONPath formatting. For example, a copied JS Path could look like `document.querySelector("#category_content > tr.tr__product.product-id-437925 > td.td__price")` , and the copied selector would be `#category_content > tr.tr__product.product-id-437925 > td.td__price` , but both of those look nothing like JSONPath formatting (from the limited research I've done, at least). I tried inputting `$..*` as the JSONPath Query, which I heard is supposed to list all elements in the document, but that ends up giving me this error:

```
ERROR: Request failed for https://pcpartpicker.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en-US"">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

I'm confused if the error message refers to the fact that the webpage is written in HTML. I thought that all web pages were written in HTML. I looked up some resources about the `muteHttpExceptions` option, but all I found were solutions involving inserting new code into the script, which I have no idea how to do (I'm not opposed to learning how to do these things, I just probably need a tutorial to figure it out)

If anyone knows how to help, I'd really appreciate it! I apologize for my lack of knowledge, I'm really new to all this...

EDIT:

The function signature is `=IMPORTJSONAPI(URL, JSONPath Query, Columns [,Parameter] [,Parameter])`. I want to fetch the data for the lowest price of a specific product or products that fall under certain filters. PCPartPicker allows the filtering of different products and sorting by price; so the link for a list of graphics cards that use the GeForce RTX 4090 Chipset, sorted by lowest price, would be https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/#sort=price&c=539
This is what I put in the URL argument of the function. For the columns argument, I've just been trying `@`, because I want to display the element that I describe.

As of writing this message, the lowest available price for GeForce RTX 4090 graphics cards is $1669.99. This is the data that I want to display on my sheet. [here's what the page looks like for me right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4I6M.png)

When I inspect the webpage using Chrome Dev Tools, hover over the price of the first graphics card on the list, and copy the JS Path, it gives me `document.querySelector("#category_content > tr.tr__product.product-id-437936 > td.td__price")` I'm confused, because this doesn't look like proper syntax for a JSONPath Query. I don't know how to format JSON, and I also don't know if pasting the element address would even yield the results that I want.

I hope my edits made things at least a little bit clearer. If you still need any clarity, feel free to ask me. I'm probably not using the right terms for many things, or being very coherent in general, so I hope I can make it up by at least being responsive. Thanks guys :)

Comment: The `Unexpected end of JSON input` error mean it's not a json, are you sure it's the good variable, or the request is well with content type json, and not by default (which can be xml) ?

Comment: Welcome. If you are using a script, then please edit your answer to include the script. It would also be helpful to include the URL that you are trying to query, and provide an example of the result that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The data on any given page of PCPartsPicker is created dynamically by Javascript. You can't access it.

Comment: @Elikill58 When I copy the JS Path for the element, it looks like the data is written in CSS and not JSON, and so it doesn't work when I paste it into the JSONPath Query. I don't know how to translate the element location into JSONPath syntax.

Comment: you can use a tool like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to verify you have a properly structured JSON

Comment: @Tedinoz I edited my post to include the function signature, the page I'm trying to fetch data from, the specific element I'm trying to fetch, and what I'm looking for as a result. I have the script itself included as a link, but I can also put it directly into the post if you'd like (I'm just worried that it's going to take up too much space)

Comment: @Tedinoz I'm aware that I can't access JSON data with normal Google Sheets functions like IMPORTXML or IMPORTHTML, but I'm pretty sure the usage of third party scripts should allow me to fetch the data, even through a dynamically changing site.

Comment: @FaridHajnal I pasted `document.querySelector("#category_content > tr.tr__product.product-id-437925 > td.td__price")`, and it verified it as valid format, but when I paste it into the function under the `JSONPath Query` argument (my function looks like this: ```=IMPORTJSONAPI("https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/#sort=price&c=539","document.querySelector('#category_content > tr.tr__product.product-id-437925 > td.td__price')","@")``` 
), it gives me the second error message I listed in my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **TL;DR:**

Can't be done on this website with `IMPORTJSON` or Sheets/Google Apps Script.

##### **Explanation:**

There are multiple reasons why this is harder than it seems and why you can't do it with your current method. You seem to be misunderstanding how the `IMPORTJSON` function works and how JSON in general works. First, the function expects a response in [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) format, which would look something like this (random example, not real data from the website):

```
{
"videocards":[
  {
    "id": 23464,
    "product": "MSI GAMING X",
    "chipset": "GeForce RTX 3060 Ti LHR",
    "price": "$626.71"
  },
  {
    "id": 32467,
    "product": "Asus ROG STRIX GAMING OC V2",
    "chipset": "GeForce RTX 3060 Ti LHR",
    "price": "$769.49"
  }]
}
//etc...
```

This is easy to parse with JSONPath. If you want to get just the product and price you can use the query `$.videocards.*.product,price` to get an output like this:

```
[
  "MSI GAMING X",
  "$626.71",
  "Asus ROG STRIX GAMING OC V2",
  "$769.49"
]
```

You can see the logic behind the query, you're getting all elements from the `videocards` node and then narrowing it down to just the `product` and `price`.

Your problem is that trying to query the URL `https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/#sort=price&c=496` won't work, because this does not just return plain JSON data, it's a full HTML website. Even worse, the site does not retrieve the product data immediately, but instead it uses JavaScript to get the data after the page loads. This is a problem for most automated tools because you need a browser or something that can simulate a browser to run JavaScript. The simple fetch done with `IMPORTJSON` won't do.

There's a way around this. Many websites have their own [API Endpoints](https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/definition/API-endpoint). These are pretty much "specialized URLs" that are used to retrieve the data in a format like JSON. In the case of `pcpartpicker.com`, one of their endpoints to get items by categories is `https://pcpartpicker.com/qapi/product/category/`. If you send the right request you can get a JSON response with the product data.

Here's a sample I made with Python that manages to retrieve results from the endpoint:

```
import requests

headers = {
   "cookie":"cf_clearance=<some-id>; xsessionid=<some-id>; xcsrftoken=<some-token>",
   "origin":"https://pcpartpicker.com",
   "referer":"https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/",
   "x-csrftoken":"<some-token>",
   "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest",
   "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
   "sec-ch-ua":"\"Google Chrome\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"111\"",
   "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

body = "sort=price&c=513&category=video-card&xslug=&location=&token=<some-id>&search=&qid=5&scr=1&scr_vw=644&scr_vh=937&scr_dw=1920&scr_dh=1080&scr_daw=1920&scr_dah=1040&scr_ddw=644&scr_ddh=1109&scr_ms=1678809379428&scr_wd=0"

response = requests.post("https://pcpartpicker.com/qapi/product/category/",  data=body, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

The issue with the above? The JSON data returned is not as simple and the response is actually the full HTML table with the products. This is probably by design and it makes it even harder to read because you now have to parse the HTML and JSONPath won't work. Yet another issue is that the request expects a session cookie that you can see I added in the headers. This helps prevent cross-site requests but also works against scraping.

You could still get the cookie and send it in your request as I did, but the final nail in the coffin is that the Google Apps Script `user-agent` in the headers is blocked. When I used the Chrome user agent it works, but using the Apps Script one I just got blank data in return. The user agent identifies the source platform so this is almost certainly on purpose to block Apps Script. You can set your own `user-agent` on other platforms, but Apps Script won't let you change it, so even if you send the right request with the right headers it won't work.

The conclusion is that you would need a lot of work to bypass all these issues, starting with needing to use a completely different scripting platform, getting the cookie, figuring out how to parse the HTML, and sending it through the Sheets API. The fact is that many websites do not like being scraped since it usually just means extra costs for them. I didn't find anything on their site but they may offer endpoints for paying customers that would be easier to use. Either way, the current approach won't work for you.